# How Optional does an implicit init call?

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I want to create an `Optional`-like enum. For the sake of example, let's say it's a replica of `Optional`:

```
public enum MyOptional<T>: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    case some(T)
    case none
    
    public init(_ some: T) { self = .some(some) }
    public init(nilLiteral: ()) { self = .none }
}
```

then I have a function and a function call:

```
func myFunc(stringParam: MyOptional<String>, intParam: MyOptional<Int>) { ... }
...
obj.myFunc(stringParam: .some("test"), intParam: .none)
```

However, I want to be able to call this function with just a literal, pretty much how `Optional` does that:

```
obj.myFunc(stringParam: "test", intParam: nil)
```

But I get compilation error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'MyOptional<String>'`. At the same time having `nil` as the second param works just fine.

I've tried to conform `MyOptional` to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, but it looks like this is not the way to go - I can't make the same type expressible by different literals.

How does `Optional` do that?

**Update:**
Ok, so conformance to `ExpressibleBy*Some*Literal` does the trick for *Some* types:

```
extension MyOptional: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral where T == Int {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) { self = .some(value) }
}

extension MuOptional: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral, ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral where T == String {
    public typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
    public typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) { self = .some(value) }
}

...

obj.myFunc(stringParam: "test", intParam: nil) // <- now this works
```

But of course it doesn't work for other classes:

```
func myFunc(userParam: MyOptional<User>) { ... }

obj.myFunc(userParam: User(name: "username")) // <- this thing doesn't work :(
```

Comment: Do you mind to share what are you trying to achieve with this design? (Why out-of-the-box Optional does not work for you ?)

Comment: @DimaG kotlin-like copy for data classes. E.g. class MyDataClass { a: Int; b: String? }; let inst1 = MyDataClass(a: 1, b: "test"); let inst2 = inst1.copy(b: nil)

Comment: It looks like in Kotlin `copy` is compiler generated per class... Are you trying to create such one generic copy function?

Comment: I don't think generic function will be possible, TBH. I have a limited number of classes that would require such behavior, so I don't mind writing copy methods manually.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, per your example with `inst2`, you want to treat `nil` as `some(T)` and not as `none`? if `nil` means no value than I think Optional can be used as-is

Comment: I don't want to pass `nil` as an indication that a field should be left as-is - in some cases I actually could assign a nil value to a copied class' field. My enum has got three cases: .some(T), .same, .none, so I can't use Optional.

Comment: It feels to me that trying to force Kotlin syntax into Swift is the wrong thing to do. Swift has `struct` for that, which are already copied when assigned. If you want a chaining behavior, then I would create a set of methods that change a single parameter, e.g. `inst1.withA(1).withB("test")`. Then you won't have any problem. You could even make a generic method using key paths, e.g. `inst1.with(\.a, 1).with(\.b, "test")`.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't see it that way - kotlin's copy method is a syntactic sugar, it is not kotlin-specific or anything like that. Allows to quickly copy data classes and change some values. The `with` suggestion could be a nice alternative, thanks for the suggestion. Although the syntax feels more verbose, and KVC is not my favorite part of Swift/objc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple - `Optional` has compiler support. There is no way to replicate that using custom code.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it seems that you are right :(. Thanks!